# Need to execute ALTER SESSION in Snowflake before using it as source in COPY Data activity in ADF. It is not allowed to run more than one statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I need to export Snowflake data to Blob storage in Azure.
I am using COPY Data Activity in ADF with Source as Snowflake.
I need to run "ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START=1;" before running the actual query for exporting the data.
ADF does not allow to run more than one statement in SOURCE in COPY activity, is there a work around for this?

I tried to pass both statments with ";" seperated as SOURCE in COPY activity but it gives syntax error.

Comment: Can you add that session parameter to your connection information instead?  I think ADF linked service for Snowflake has additional properties that can be passed in that should relate to any session parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and reply here.

Answer (score 0):

**That's correct. In ADF, the SOURCE in COPY activity only allows one statement to be run at a time.**

***The work around can be as below:***

As you want to execute two statements on Snowflake data source **In Copy activity only Specify the SQL query to read data from Snowflake** And execute another statement in another activity before copy activity.

- First you can Use **`Scripct activity`** to perform your `ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START=1;` on the Snowflake data source and then use copy activity to copy the data.

[image]

Comment: But will the second statement run in the same session? The Script Activity will set the parameter at Session level and that session will be dropped after execution.

Comment: if they are using different sessions then execute all your statements through script activity and then you can store the script activity result in blob storage in the form of json file.